# Automation git pull doesn't work on server with cron and url

Tags: php, git, cron, pull

I want to pulling commits from git repo automatically. I have ready server where I can't use ssh and make configuration becouse I don't have permission but I remember login and password in git files.

For automation I want to use cron or place php file with script in public folder. I writed script:

```
<?php system('echo "Updating";'); ?>
<?php system('cd project && ls -al && pwd && git pull'); ?>
```

When I run it with php72-cli(it's version of php on server) script.php it's work and pull commits. When I run it in broswer by url myurl.com/script.php it showing text 'Updating' but didn't update. I made script executable by chmod + x.

I thing raeson of that is problem with wrong rights or access but I don't know how to find error and fix it. I can think wrong.

Comment: May be wrong paths. What is output of pwd, when you run script in browser and in cli?

Comment: Path of place work scripts is good.

Comment: 1. If your main directory with codes is named "web" for example, document_root of your web server points on "web" or "web/project"?
2. Which config file of web server.
3. Which permissions on php-script. Print "ls -l" in directory with script.